Data migration using parallel processing in python
I have a python script in the local environment that pulls data from sql server, loads it into a pandas dataframe and then writes the dataframe into bigquery using big query client.
The problem is the data in question, which has 1.9 billion records and I was thinking of using parallel processing in python to kind of speed this process up.
I tried chunking the data loading part where a chunk was 1 million records, but still its going to take a lot of time to get this done.
Is there any way to pull this off? Or are there any other ways to efficiently migrate this data?
Below is the script I am using:
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc 
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Connection string
conn_str = f'DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password}'
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)

# Initial query to get the first batch
sql_query = f"SELECT TOP 1000000 * FROM {table_name} ORDER BY id"
last_id = 0

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    autodetect=True,
    write_disposition = "WRITE_APPEND",
)

while True:
    df = pd.read_sql(sql_query, conn)
    
    if df.empty:
        break
    
    # Write the DataFrame to BigQuery
    job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, table_ref, job_config=job_config)
    job.result()  # Wait for the job to complete
    
    # Update the last_id to the last seen in the DataFrame
    last_id = df['id'].iloc[-1]
    
    # Prepare the next query
    sql_query = f"SELECT TOP 1000000 * FROM {table_name} WHERE id> {last_id} ORDER BY id"

    print(f"Loaded up to ID: {last_id}")

# Close the database connection
conn.close()


I'm not sure a python script is the right tool for this size of data migration - have you considered looking at other data pipelines like in the bigquery documentation? (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided/sqlserver-to-bigquery)

I would probably not suggest using a python script as the right tool for this size of data migration. Instead, I would consider referencing google's dataflow documentation and using some kind of batched pipeline to connect your sql server instance to bigquery, as illustrated in the documentation
